# Count elements in ajax/json response

Tags: ajax

This is properly pretty simple and has been asked many times before, but it just eludes me, who to do it.
I have 2 dropdowns, where the last one gets populated from the select of the first one. That works, but now I want to preselect for the second dropdown, when there is only one element in the response.

**Function:**

```
                    $( "select[name='r53b']" ).change(function () {
                    var r53bID = $(this).val();
                    if(r53bID) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "/overfladeajax.php",
                            dataType: 'Json',
                            data: {'id':r53bID},
                            success: function(data) {
                                $('select[name="r53c"]').empty();
                                    $('select[name="r53c"]').append('<option value="">Vælg Lagtykkelse</option>');
                                $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                                    $('select[name="r53c"]').append('<option value="'+ key +'">'+ value +'</option>');
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
```

**2 kind of reponses:**

```
{"7":"2 x 100 \u03bcm HS 150 (totalt 200 \u03bcm t\u00f8rfilm)","8":"1 x 40 \u03bcm zink primer + 1 x 120 \u03bcm HS 150 (totalt 160 \u03bcm t\u00f8rfilm)"}
```

or

```
{"2":"1 x 80 \u03bcm HS 150"}
```

How to I make the append, so it will also select the option where only one is available?

Comment: Hi ,you mean if only one option is there that option should be set as selected ?

Comment: Yes, that is was I'm looking for.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys(yourjson).length` to get the length of keys in your json object and then if the count is `1` add `selected` to that options.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var data = {
  "2":"1 x 80 \u03bcm HS 150"
}

var count = Object.keys(data).length//get key length
console.log("length is "+count)
$('select[name="r53c"]').append('<option value="">Vælg Lagtykkelse</option>');

$.each(data, function(key, value) {
  //if length is 1
  if (count == 1) {
    $('select[name="r53c"]').append('<option selected value="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>');
  } else {
    $('select[name="r53c"]').append('<option  value="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="r53c">
</select>
```

Comment: Yeah, it was easy. I was trying to a selected variable into the append part, but couldn't get that to work. Thanks